# Associative arrays - ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I know I can declare an associative "array" like:

```
var myData = {
    foo: 'val1',
    bar: 'val2',
    baz: 'val3'
};
```

What's standard practice in declaring associative arrays in ES6?

Comment: That's not an associative array, that's an object literal. ES6 continues to support JavaScript's literal syntax, which is a superset of what eventually became the JSON data interchange format.

Comment: i know thats why I put array in quotes

Comment: There are a couple of new things on ES6 regarding object literals (shorthands, computed properties, etc), but this is still pretty standard.

Answer (score 4):

Objects are associations of string keys and arbitrary values.

ES6 introduces maps, which are associations of arbitrary keys and arbitrary values.

```
var m = new Map([
  ['a', 'b'],
  [1, 2],
  [true, false]
]);
m.get('a'); // 'b'
```

There is no "standard practice", but maps can be considered when you want to associate values.